# In javascript how to check current date with three dates

Tags: javascript

In Javascript how to check  current datetime with three dates. i want to disable the radio button if date is pervious datetime.i need to validate the date according to current datetime 
 suppose a)10/2/2017 11:00  b)21/3/2018 11:20 c)28/4/2018 14:00 
above three dates i need to block the radio button and stike the date in javascript

```
 function formatAMPM(date) { // This is to display 12 hour format like 
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
        var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
        return strTime;
        }


        var myDate = new Date();
        var displayDate = myDate.getMonth()+ '/' +myDate.getDate()+ '/' +myDate.getFullYear()+ ' ' +formatAMPM(myDate);
        alert(displayDate);
        var dt = Date.parse(displayDate);
        var d = Date.parse(ts);
        var d1 = Date.parse(ts1);
        var d2 = Date.parse(ts2);
        alert(d);
        alert(dt);
```

Comment: You'll need to post some of your code and more precisely explain what you want, we don't know what you're referring to.

Answer (score -1):

There is a good library [momemt](https://momentjs.com/docs/) you can use that to check whether date is current date. You can use [isBefore](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/)

Also if you want to use JS only you can do the following:

Convert your date string in Date object and get the time in milliseconds and then compare it to Date.now().